# Measure of set of lines in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose I have a set $A=\bigcup_{z_x} \bigcup_{z_y}A(z_x,z_y) $ where $z_x,z_y \in \mathbb{Z}$ and
\begin{align}
A(z_x,z_y)=\left\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: xz_x-yz_y=0 \right\}
\end{align}

The measure of $A$ is  $0$, right?

Since, the measure of  $A(z_x,z_y)$ (this just a line) is $0$ and union of sets of measure $0$ is $0$.

Is this correct?

Comment: What do you know about the $z_x$ and $z_y$? Does the union run over all real numbers? Some subset of the real numbers?

Comment: A union of *countably many* sets of measure 0 is of measure 0. So, if you have a countable set of lines, sure. If not, $A$ can be as big as you want, so no.

Comment: Your definition of $A(z_x,z_y)$ appears to have a typo.

Comment: @UmbertoP. I added what is the domain of $z_x$ and $z_y$.

Comment: @UmbertoP. Could you point out what is wrong with that definition?

Comment: @Alex there is no $z_y$ in the definition of $A(z_x,z_y)$.

Comment: @UmbertoP. Thanks I would never catch that. I made corrections.

Answer (score 1):

The space of (unoriented) lines in the plane is, topologically, equivalent to a non-orientable two-manifold. I'm not sure if this helps from a measure theory point of view, but here goes.

A line in the plane is given by an equation of the form $ax+by+c=0$, where $a$, $b$ and $c$ are real numbers. Moreover, $a$ and $b$ cannot both be zero at the same time - we wouldn't have a line.

The triples $(a,b,c)$ and $(\lambda a,\lambda b,\lambda c)$ give the same line for all $\lambda \neq 0$ since
$$(\lambda a)x + (\lambda b)y + (\lambda c)=0 \iff \lambda(ax+by+c)=0 \iff ax+by+c=0$$

The set of non-zero triples, $(a,b,c)$ under the equivalence relation $(a,b,c) \sim (\lambda a,\lambda b, \lambda c)$ is the real projective plane $\mathbb{RP}^2$. It is a smooth two dimensional manifold and can be parametrised by homogeneous coordinates $(a:b:c)$.

As mentioned $a=b=0$ does not give a line, so the space of (unoriented) lines in the plane is given by $\mathbb{RP}^2$, minus the point $(0:0:c)=(0:0:1)$. Topologically, this is an *open* Möbius band. That is, a Möbius band with the boundary circle deleted.

Comment: So, your argument confirms that the measure is 0, right?

Comment: @Alex What make you think that this argument "confirms" that the measure is zero?

Comment: I was just asking. Unfortunately, I know nothing of the math you used.