# Find the transition functions and show that $M$ is non-orientable.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, differential-geometry, manifolds

Let $M$ be the collection of all affine lines on the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$. Introduce an atlas of two charts on $M$. The chart $U_1$ consists of all non-vertical lines, and the line $L : y = a_1x +b_1$ has coordinates $(a_1, b_1)$. The chart $U_2$ consists of all non-horizontal lines and the line $L : x = a_2y + b_2$ has coordinates $(a_2, b_2)$. Find the transition functions and show that $M$ is connected and non-orientable.

I understand what a transition function is, but I'm not sure how to find them. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/926506/3217

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $L:U_1\rightarrow R^2$ defined by $L(y=a_1x+b_1)=(a_1,b_1)$.

$M:U_2\rightarrow R^2$ defined by $M(x=a_2y+b_2) =(a_2,b_2)$. You have to compute $L\circ M^{-1}$ and $M\circ L^{-1}$.

You have $M^{-1}(a,b)=(x=ay+b)$. You can write $y=x/a-b/a$, So $L\circ M^{-1}(a,b)=L(x=ax+b)=L(y=x/a-b/a) = (1/a,-b/a)$.

With the same method, compute $M\circ L^{-1}(a,b)$.

To show that it is not orientable, compute the determinant of the Jacobian of the transition functions and show that its sign is negative for $a<0$ and positive for $a>0$.

Comment: You have not shown that $M$ is not orientable but only that your particular atlas does not give an orientation To illustrate my point, I'll  consider on  $\mathbb R$ the atlas given by the two charts $f_i: U_i\to \mathbb R$, with $i=0,1$ , $U_i=\mathbb R$ and $f_i(x)=(-i)^i x$. The determinant of the jacobian of the transition functions  is $-1$ but although my stupid but legitimate atlas does not provide an orientation,  $\mathbb R$ is nevertheless  an orientable manifold!

Comment: Suppose a manifold is covered by 2 connected charts and is orientable. One can argue as follows that you must be able to 'fix' the charts to produce charts whose transition functions have positive Jacobian. First, note the coordinate frames in each chart either agree with the orientation or they do not throughout the entire chart, as the chart is a connected set. If the coordinate frames from a chart agree with the orientation, leave the chart alone, and if they disagree, compose the chart with an orientation reversing map $\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ to get a new chart.

Comment: (Cont.) These 2 modified charts will have positive Jacobian. (This is consistent, e.g., with Georges Elencwajg's comment.) However, if you assume the manifold above is orientable, this argument gives you a contradiction. There's no way to modify the charts you have by composing with an orientation reversing map of $\mathbb{R}^2$ so that the Jacobian is positive. This is clear if you think about the transition map. It's defined on $\mathbb{R}^2-\{y-axis\}$ and flips the right half vertically without also flipping the left half vertically.